# There is no row at position 0 Vb.net and Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to get and print data from a row "status" on the table "printer" and it keeps saying "There is no row at position 0."

```
 Dim conn As New deepconnection()
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim ds, ds1 As New DataSet
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM printer", conn.getConnection)
    conn.openOcean()
    PrinterStatus.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("status")
```

The connection:

```
 Private fishcatch As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=xxxxx;database=deep_ocean")

' Get the connection only to read
ReadOnly Property getConnection() As MySqlConnection
    Get
        Return fishcatch
    End Get
End Property
```

Open connection:

```
Sub openOcean()
    If fishcatch.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        fishcatch.Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

What is wrong?

Comment: By the way, downloading a whole database table just so you can get the first row is a waste of resources. Add a limit clause to your SQL if you only need one row

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually exit the command. You set the SQL command text and open the connection, but you must also then execute the SQL statement(s).

Comment: Also, I see lots of people try to create wrappers for the DbConnection objects, and it's almost always a mistake. Thanks to connection pooling, your DbConnection is **already** a wrapper around a pool of real connections, and by making your own wrapper you optimize the small/light thing at the expense of breaking the existing optimizations already provided for you around the larger/heavier real underlying connections. It's really okay to just make and open a new connection object for most queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't executed the command to fill the table. Without that part the table is still empty

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM printer", conn.getConnection)
conn.openOcean()

' Execute the command and pass the reader to the table load method
table.Load(command.ExecuteReader())

PrinterStatus.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("status")
```

Even after this the table could still be empty if there is no record in the database table named Printer, so before reading anything from a datatable check always the rows count

```
If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    PrinterStatus.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("status")
    ...
End If
```